# how to pass and insert id in controller store laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, controller

in view

```
 <form action="{{route('memberPost', $courses->id)}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <button type="submit" class="btn clever-btn mb-30 w-100">Ikut course</button>
      </form>
```

in controller

```
public function detail_courses($slug){

    $courses = Course::where('slug', $slug)->first();
    return view('single-courses', compact('courses','id_courses'));
}
public function memberPost(Request $request, $id){
    $courses = Course::where('id', $id)->first();
    $id_courses = $courses->id;
    $member = Member::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'course_id' => $id_courses
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('detail_courses');
    

}
```

in route

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['checkRole']], function () {
    Route::get('/single-courses/{slug}', 'PagesController@detail_courses')->name('detail_courses');
    Route::post('/single-courses/{slug}/{id}', 'PagesController@memberPost')->name('memberPost');
});
```

When I was trying the code above, instead an error like this occurred Missing required parameters for [Route: memberPost] [URI: single-courses / {slug} / {id}].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route named memberPost has another parameter($slug) that needs to be passed

```
Route::post('/single-courses/{slug}/{id}', 'PagesController@memberPost')->name('memberPost');
```

In your form action's route, you need to pass the slug as well

```
{{route('memberPost', ['slug' => $courses->slug, 'id' => $courses->id])}}
```